# how get magento cron events list?

Tags: php, magento, cron

in cron.php there are these lines:

```
Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
if ($isShellDisabled) {
    Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
 } 
 ...
```

how to debug all the events that are called by

```
  Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
```

and

```
  Mage::dispatchEvent('always'); ?
```

I need to access all events that should be called with cron.

Any link, article or response related are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of scheduled cron jobs?

Comment: yes, exactly! or the list of job that are registerd as "always"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to see this would be:

`Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode('crontab/jobs');`

You may want to neatly print_r that. It has name, scheduling, model information, etc. That method is fine for some temporary debugging.

If you want a neater (and more professional) way of doing this, there are quite a few free extensions for it. See:

- **My favorite, https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler**.
  Note that Aoe_Scheduler also always you to manually schedule, disable, kill, ad hoc run (and more) the individual crons from the backend, in addition to seeing list and scheduled timeline views.
- https://gist.github.com/werdan/5827225